# project based on python3.6 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python

I need to move django app from ubuntu 16 to 20.04, it's based on python 3.6 but default for ubuntu is 3.8. There's also cron jobs, uwsgi etc
I'm not a python dev, what would be the best approach? Do I need to use venv and activate in every cron job?

Comment: What is stopping you from testing the app on the Ubuntu 20.04 machine? You can make adjustments if it there is an issue or compile Python 3.6 and have the app use it.

Comment: I'm a java dev and found in python that some errors occurs only during runtime, it's too risky from my point of view and actually not easy to fix them due to some quite old libraries are used. Anyway it seems with venv and rewriting systemd services everything is working fine